# What is the story of bhairava temple in Ujjain

Tags: bhairava

[image]

What is the history of bhairava temple in Ujjain?i have Heard that it is mentioned in skanda Purana and Shiva Purana but couldn't find the reference,and why he is offered liquor

Answer (score 1):

The story is mentioned in [Āvantya-khaṇḍa of The Skanda Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc425570.html), [Chapter 64 - (The Pilgrimage to Kālabhairava Tīrtha)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc425636.html). Quoting verses from there:

> ##### Vyāsa said:
>
> 3b-4. At what time did this Tīrtha called **Kālabhairava** become renowned, O excellent sage; narrate this in great detail.

On hearing that,

> ##### Sanatkumāra said:
>
> **5-6.** Formerly this Yogin Bhairava caused great fight to Yoginīs. There were Kṛtyās created by Kālacakra (Time-cycle). Among them the Yoginī called Kālī is well-known as the greatest and most excellent. The pure Bhairava was brought up like her son by that Yoginī.
> 7. O excellent one, all the three types of defects and calamities well-known in the world as the causes of all types of great obstacles, were destroyed by him.
> **8-10a.** Kālakṛtyās also were dislodged by that noble-souled one. They are nine and are known as Mātṛkās, viz. Mahāmārī, Pūtanā, Kṛtyā, Śakunī, Revatī, Khalā, Koṭari, Tāmasī and Māyā. They are vicious and bring in calamities to the wicked ones. They cause great terror to all living beings. That pious-souled one (i.e. Bhairava) brought them under control and made (them) bestowers of boons of all desires.

Next verses 10 and 11a, can be used to validate its current presence in Ujjain:

> **10b-11a.** **He is stationed in the splendid northern bank of Śiprā**. He is also stationed in the far east of the Ūṣara (desert land) forever.

In next verses from 11b to 15, it is mentioned how one should worship him, quoting the same here:

> **11b-15.** Men should be of steady mind. They should retain great concentration of the mind. On the eighth, ninth, and fourteenth days of the bright half of Āṣāḍha, especially when it coincides with a Sunday, they should perform special Pūjās to bring in auspiciousness at the time of marriage, birth of a son and other auspicious occasions. **They must worship (Bhairava) in the form of the bestower of boons, with leaves, flowers, excellent scents, Naivedyas (food offerings) of various kinds, betel leaves, incense etc. They should propitiate Brāhmaṇas with meals and the great Lord with Homas.** This brings a great welfare. This is the great auspiciousness. After bowing down to that Lord, they should eulogize thus for the achievement of all desired objects.

As you can see there is no explicit mention of wine offerings. I could not find the sanskrit verses to cross check.

Comment: Thank you for answering,so is the liquor offering a vamcara pratice then?

Comment: Yes as per wikipedia. Panchamakara offering were practiced before. Now it is just wine offering. Could be because normal people have started visiting that place more often than before; since the practice itself is very secret, it can not be performed in public. I had visited this place during my graduation back in 2009. It was very dark when we had reached early morning and it was kind of scary lol.